# Reading directory using file api : how to handle a directory containing 20000-30000 files?

Tags: java, file-io, directory, iteration

I in the process of writting a simple java program which reads the contents of the directory 
and print out the names of the files and last modified time .

The issue i forsee is , the vault i am reading is pretty huge and there are some case where 
the files in a single directory can well exceed 20000.
Using file api

```
    `file.listFiles()`
```

would inturn create 20000 file objects, my concern this 
could slow down the process , may be bloat the memory as well.

Is there a way to batch i.e to tell java to scan the directory in terms of 50 files at a time or atleast iterate one file at a time instead of loading all objects in memory at once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a java.nio.file.FileVisitor via java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(...). It has been introduced in Java 7 exactly for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about the memory, I would worry about the disk access time for those files.

The access time for a file can be 8 ms, even for a SSD it can be 100 micro-seconds. The time it takes to create a File object can be less than a micro-second.

You are right that 20,000 File objects is non trivial, but if this your main problem you are doing very well.

You can use `list()` instead which will be slightly more memory efficient and create File only as you need them.

Comment: But then to access the last modified timestamp , i would have to create a File Object with the file Name , that can only slow the process ..dont you think

Comment: It would make a difference of a few micro-seconds, far less than a single file lastModified() access. I would write the code in the simplest way you can.